# Fast reading and writing lor large fasta files

Tags: python, rust, bioinformatics

I wanted to write some code which reads in a fasta file and one hot encodes the sequence which is consequentially saved to a file . A fasta file is a text based file format commonly used in bioinformatics. Here's an example:

```
>chr1
ACGTCTCGTGC
NNNNNNNNNNN
ACGTTGGGGGG
>chr2
AGGGTCTGGGT
NNNNNNNNNNN
```

It has a header string with `>` and then some genetic sequence following. Every character in that sequence represents a nucleotide. For example "A" stands for Adenine and "N" for unknown. The number of possible characters in the sequence is limited, but there are some encodings allowing different representations. But this is not that important for me, since I will probably filter beforehand anyway.

The output should be a text file with the one hot encoded sequence and the header for identification.  Depending on how one would choose the encoding this could look something like this for the first three nucleotides(`ACG`):

```
>chr1
0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0
0,0,1,0
```

I wrote some Rust code together to achieve this and it works, but it seems to be pretty slow. Maybe I should also mention at this point that the fasta files can get really big (many GB) in no time. I tried my code with an ~60MB .fa file and took about ~2m.30s and some generic python code i wrote together in 10 minutes took only ~40s.

Now I wanted to know why my Rust Code is slower then it's python equivalent and whether I did it right in an idiomatic rust way? Also I do not want to store the data in something like HDF5. I just want to understand Rust better. Especially I/O heavy text processing tasks, since these are common in bioinformatics.

Here's the Code I wrote:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Write};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::env;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main()  -> std::io::Result<()>{

    // gather cmd arguments
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect(); 
    let filename: &String = &args[1];
    let outfile: &String = &args[2];

    // Open the file to read from
    let file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();

    // Create a buffered reader -> instead of reading everything to ram
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines = reader.lines(); 

    // this allows to open a file in file append mode to write (or create it)
    let mut to_write_file = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true) // Optionally create 
        .open(outfile)
        .expect("Unable to open file");

    // iterate over every line
    for l in lines {

        // check if we get a string back (Result<String, Error>)
        if let Ok(line_string) = l {

            // check for header lines
             if line_string.contains("chr"){
                 println!("Processing: {}",line_string);
                 // write to file so we can keep track of chroms
                 writeln!(to_write_file, "{}",line_string).unwrap();
             }
             else {
                 // iterate over nucleotides
                 for character in line_string.chars() {
                     // one hot encode the nucleotide
                     let nucleotide: String = one_hot_encode_string(String::from(character));
                     writeln!(to_write_file,"{}", nucleotide)?;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn one_hot_encode_string(nucleotide: String) -> String {
    // One hot encodes a Nucleotide: String

    let encoding: String; // create return variable

    // OHE the nucleotide
    match nucleotide.as_str() {
    "A" => encoding = String::from("0,0,0,1"),
    "G" => encoding = String::from("0,0,1,0"),
    "C" => encoding = String::from("0,1,0,0"),
    "T" => encoding = String::from("1,0,0,0"),
    "N" => encoding = String::from("0,0,0,0"),
    _ => encoding = String::from("NA"),
    }
    encoding
    
}
```

Her's also the "naive" python code:

```py
import sys
# one hot encode nulceotide
def ohe(nucleotide: str) -> str:
    if nucleotide == "A":
        return("0,0,0,1")
    if nucleotide == "G":
        return("0,0,1,0")
    if nucleotide == "T":
        return("0,1,0,0")
    if nucleotide == "C":
        return("1,0,0,0")
    if nucleotide == "N":
        return("0,0,0,0")
    else:
        return("NA")

def main() -> None:
    # get arguments
    input: str = sys.argv[1]
    output: str = sys.argv[2]

    # open in file
    with open(input) as in_f:
        # open out file
        with open(output, 'a') as out_f:
            for line in in_f:
                # get header
                if line.startswith(">"):
                    out_f.write(f"{line.rstrip()}\n")
                else:
                    # iterate over every nucleotide
                    for character in line.rstrip():
                        # one hot encode character
                        # print(ohe(character))
                        out_f.write(f"{ohe(character)}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run with `cargo run --release`? Debug-mode Rust can be quite slow.

Comment: Either way, this question is more suited for the Code Review Stack Exchange, since it's about working-but-suboptimal code.

Comment: Some comments I can think of though: you're allocating `String`s where `str` constants would do, and e.g. wrapping the single `A`/`G`/`T`/ `C` character in a String, where just a character comparison would do.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will post it there and try the release flag!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to link the Code Review SE question in a comment here, when you've gotten it posted :)

Comment: As promised: here's the link to the now posted Code Review Questions: [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272415/rust-program-to-one-hot-encode-genetic-seuqneces-from-fa-files). Also the release flag helped immensely and brought down the time from 2m30s to 1m30s. Next I will try what you recommended regarding the chars and str methods. Thank you @AKX!

Comment: @dry-leaf  since this stuff is fresh in your head now maybe you would find something familiar in https://gist.github.com/TomConlin/6cd976151d36dd3e2a9fb34842b9c66e

Comment: @tomc: thanks for this. Really interesting!